# Error 404 with IIS 6.0

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-6

What is the meaning of `sc-status 404 sc-substatus 0 sc-win32-status 2 in IIS 6.0 Log`?

Please Help.

Comment: Did you try Googling the problem before you posted here? This appears to be a simple "404 Page not found" error. You have undoubtedly seen this while surfing around the internet many times.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Page not found.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page after a simple search: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380 (I hope you get it in your language)

> 404.0 = file or folder not found